# Drush cron - how to provide the actual task

Tags: 7, drush, cron

Based on [this documentation](http://drush.readthedocs.org/en/master/cron/index.html?highlight=core-cron) the drush cron can be set up as

> 10 * * * * /usr/bin/env
> PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
> COLUMNS=72 /usr/local/drush/drush --root=/path/to/your/drupalroot
> --uri=your.drupalsite.org --quiet cron

Where is the actual task being set here? I would like to invoke a certain url on each cron run. How do I provide that url to be ran in this cron or invoke a function using this drush cron.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "run a particular page"?

Comment: Updated to clarify that to invoke a certain url

Answer (score 1):

From the Drupal perspective, you just need to implement [`hook_cron()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_cron/7):

```
function MYMODULE_cron() {
  drupal_http_request('http://foo.bar');
}
```

That will be invoked on all normal cron runs (there are situations when it won't, e.g. if you have a cron management module installed that limits core cron operations).

But it might make more sense just to wget/curl that URL on a separate single-line cron job. Depends on your use case, but either will probably be fine.

Comment: So seems that drush cron would actually run all the hook module crons. Is there a way to run only a particular hook_cron rather than all of the?